# How to schedule a task and run at system start in wix?

Tags: wix, installation, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a task through wix custom action.After installing the installer the installer is adding the task in the scheduler tasks.But the task is not running at the scheduled time.Please give any solution.

What should I need to give in Directory attribute.

The code that I am using is :

```
  <Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id="CreateScheduledTask"
      Return="check"
      Impersonate="no"
      Execute="deferred"
      Directory="TARGETDIR"
      ExeCommand="&quot;[SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE&quot; /CREATE /SC ONSTART /TN &quot;LaunchMyApp &quot;  /TR &quot;[INSTALLDIR]AppDesktopFiles\AppLaunch.exe&quot; /RU &quot;NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM&quot; /RP /F" >
    </CustomAction>

    <CustomAction
    Id="RemoveScheduledTask"
    Return="ignore"
    Directory="ProgramFilesFolder"
    ExeCommand= "&quot;[SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE&quot; /DELETE /TN LaunchMyApp /F" >
    </CustomAction>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CreateScheduledTask" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
      <Custom Action="RemoveScheduledTask" Before="RemoveFiles">Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

  </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the task is created ok and you see it in the list, it doesn't seem like it's a WiX issue. The task should run at reboot. Can you isolate the specific problem to:

1. The task doesn't start at all.
2. The task starts but it doesn't launch your app.

Anyway, I don't believe your app will launch given that specification because there is no desktop folder when the system starts because nobody has logged on, and the system account is an internal account that does not have a desktop folder.

Comment: The task status showing the status as running.But originally it is not running .

Comment: If your app has a UI and you can't see it, well any app that does not originate via the interactive user won't UI into the user's desktop. If there's nobody logged on at that time the app might not start because it might require an interactive user. As far as I know, only services start when the system starts. Everything else requires a user to logon.

Comment: If I am using /RU "currently logged on username" it is working  fine.It is showing on desktop.If I am using /RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" it is failed to show the running task on desktop.

Comment: I tried with directly command prompt also , it is showing same behaviour.